# Render drupal form in custom template

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to render DRUPAL content type form in a custom tpl that I created. But its just printing the hidden fields not the actual form.

I tried using `drupal_get_form` and `drupal_render`, but nothing works!

Can someone suggest me a link or reference to drupal theming guide?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `drupal_get_form` and `drupal_render` on 2 different steps.

```
$myForm = drupal_get_form('YOUR_FORM_ID');
print drupal_render($myForm);
```